# How to sort a csv file alphabetically row by row

Tags: python-3.x, csv, sorting

i would like to sort a text file alphabetically, row by row. But i have this problem.

The output file:

ALPHA,1,2,3,4,5DELTA,1,2,3,4,5

GAMMA,1,2,3,4,5

ZZZZ,1,2,3,4,5
,,,,,

and this is what i want:

ALPHA,1,2,3,4,5

DELTA,1,2,3,4,5

GAMMA,1,2,3,4,5

ZZZZ,1,2,3,4,5
,,,,,

This is my code, Thanks!!!

```
with open('USUARIOS.CSV') as archivo:
    with open('archivoTEMP.CSV', 'w') as archivoTEMP:
        for linea in sorted(archivo):
            archivoTEMP.write(linea)

with open('archivoTEMP.CSV', 'r') as archivoTEMP:
    with open(nombreArchivo, 'w') as archivo:
        copyfileobj(archivoTEMP,archivo)
        archivo.write(',,,,,')

 os.remove('archivoTEMP.CSV')
```

Comment: Post the input data `USUARIOS.CSV`, the problem is in there... And cool it with the caps lock.